# watchOS 2 - Replace visible controllers

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos, wkinterfacecontroller

I'm working on an app for watchOS 2 with a paged based navigation. However, I'd like to set some of the controllers dynamically. I know I could call the following:

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(names, contexts: contexts)
```

That way, I am able to change the controllers dynamically. But it seems that I have to set all controllers every time. That instantiates new controllers for every entry. Instead of that, I'd like to only *append* view controllers while keeping the context and instance variables of the first controller in order to not hit the network again. Is this currently supported with watchOS 2?